# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = xxx@gmail.com limit 1)

Tags: mysql, laravel

subi a mi host mi proyecto hecho en Laravel y al momento de iniciar sesion tengo el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = xxxx@gmail.com limit 1)
```

Cambie los datos del .env pero sigue sin andar.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:xswkMZrX8i7QPukJm0eRuSxyt9wGke6QshIzMaZX4J4=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://subdominio en el que subi el proyecto

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=ip del servidor de mi host
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=nombre de mi base de datos
DB_USERNAME=usuario 
DB_PASSWORD=mi password
```

No entiendo que me falta cambiar o si cambie algo que no debia, para poder utilizar esta base de datos. Les agradeceria de su ayudar.

Comment: Prueba con `DB_HOST=localhost` o `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ no esta hosteado en un servidor local, sino que esta hosteado con un servidor FTP

Comment: ¿La base de datos está en un servidor remoto? Típicamente la BD está en el mismo servidor que la aplicación... y no tiene nada que ver con FTP

Comment: Utiliza php artisan config:cache para refrescar

Comment: Claro la base de datos cuando estaba en desarrollo la utilizaba con xampp, pero tengo entendido que al subirla al host debo utilizar la ip que me brinda el servicio de host, ya que la base de datos la exporte y la agregue a un usuario del hosting con una nueva base de datos donde la importe. @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Si utilizo como db_host: localhost o 127.0.0.1 sigo teniendo el mismo error @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Definido en mysql un usario con el ip del servidor web?  Es decir user@127.0.0.1 es differente a user@192.168.0.1

Comment: Si la IP de la base de datos es distinta a la del host de tu proyecto, debes crear un usuario en MySQL <usuario>@<host> y otorgarle permisos hacia la base de datos. ¿Tienes un panel de control (CPanel, Plesk, etc.)?

Comment: @sal Si tengo un panel de control, ya tengo un usuario con el host, donde puse mi base de datos. Es decir extraje mi base de datos de MySQL y la importe en la nueva base de datos que cree con el nuevo usuario y el host. El tema es que nose si estoy llenando bien los datos del .env en Laravel, o si es un error particularmente de mi base de datos.